# What are the uses of ethyl phthalate

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, toxicity, identification

The last time I went to my junior college I remember seeing huge blue colored drums labeled *ethyl phthalate*. So just out of curiosity I decided to check upon this compound. [Wikipedia entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diethyl_phthalate) containes some information about it's toxicity and usage, but I couldn't understand that part clearly. Could someone help me by listing the possible uses and properties of *ethyl phthalate*?

Comment: It's commonly used as an organic solvent is fairly benign as such things go. Was this in a chemistry department storage facility of similar?

Comment: Its main use, the reason for barrels, was a heat exchange medium in liquid heating baths. It has been replaced by heating mantles and silicone oils.

Answer (score 2):

[Wikipedia — Diethylphthalat (German)](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diethylphthalat#Verwendung) contains more use-cases for ethyl phthalate:

- Formulation auxiliaries for plant protection products;
- Fixer for fragrances;
- In the process of ethanol denaturing;
- In manufacturing of cellulose esters as a very well-gelling and light-resistant plasticizer;
- A plasticizer for cellulose-based varnish binders and as enteric coating for medicaments;
- A part of cosmetic products due to its film-forming, softening and hair-conditioning properties;
- [Explosives phlegmatizer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phlegmatized);
- A carrier in the dyeing process of cellulose acetate or triacetate fibers.